# number variable won't addition by 1 and display in a label everytime the timer counts 1000ms. - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, timer

Here is my code:

```
 number = 1
    If chkFN.Enabled = True Then
    If ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
             number += 1
             lblFN2.Text = number
        Else
             lblFN2.Text = "0"
        End If
    End If
```

i have a checkbox, progressbar and a label.

when the progress bar is lower than 100 i want the number variable to + 1 every time the timer counts 1. I've tried "X = X + 1" - it worked to a point but i need to reset the variable to "0" when the progressbar hits 100% and when i click the stop button.

while I've been typing this i've also tried:

```
        X = X + 1

    If chkFN.Enabled = True Then
        If ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
            lblFN2.Text = X + 1
        ElseIf AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded   
        Then
            X = 0
            lblFN2.Text = "0"
        Else
            X = 0
            lblFN2.Text = "0"
        End If
    End If
```

But when you start the timer again it just resumes from it's last number e.g. "13" and doesn't reset to "0".

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: Where is the event that turns the timer back on or off? I'm assuming your not setting the value back to zero in this event.

Comment: Show the method declarations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use your first code, but add in

number += 1

to the Else condition.  You need to reset the variable or it just increments it again.

Comment: i tried what you said, i think?         Dim number As Integer
        number += 1
        If chkFN.Enabled = True Then
            If ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
                number += 1
                lblFN2.Text = number
            Else
                number = 0
                lblFN2.Text = "0"
            End If
        End If       but it didnt work it didnt go past 2?

Comment: Why are you incrementing number before the If statement as well as within it?  I think you only need the one within the If statement